# MDX -Count based on earlier sale

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I have a table in **Data warehouse**, simplified as follows - **Fact Sales**:

```
Date(MMddYYYY)  Customer  Product
01-02-2020      1         1
01-02-2020      2         1
02-01-2020      3         2
02-09-2020      3         1
02-02-2020      4         2
04-02-2020      1         2
```

I want to count the products, but I only want to count product 2 if the customer already have bought product 1 before product 2. And I want to place the product 2 purchase in the same month as product 1.

> Is this possible to achieve with MDX?

The result should look like this:

```
Month   Product1  Product2 
jan-20  2         1
feb-20  1         0
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say it is impossible but,If you want to change the data like this

> And I want to place the product 2 purchase in the same month as product 1.

It is more convenient and possible by using SQL instead of MDX which is not strong at this.